# Adding SSL certs to Samba from CA

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, ldap, samba

I have a wildcard SSL cert from A CA that I am trying to get to work on my samba ADDC. Samba will fail on Samba restart when smb.conf looks like this:

```
    tls enabled  = yes
    tls keyfile  = tls/mycert.crt
    tls certfile = tls/thekey.p7b
    tls cafile   = tls/myca.ca-bundle
    # client ldap sasl wrapping = sign and seal
    ldap server require strong auth = allow_sasl_over_tls
```

It fails with a "TLS failed to initialise certfile...and keyfile"
Trying to verify the cert also comes back as this error

error 20 at 0 depth lookup: unable to get local issuer certificate
error verification failed

Also converted the files to PEM files and tried that but switched them back when it wasnt working.

Any help with this would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have misread the [man page for the samba conf file](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html).  The following options need adjustment in your config:

> ###### tls keyfile (G)
>
> This option can be set to a file (PEM format)
> containing the RSA private key. This file must be accessible without a
> pass-phrase, i.e. it must not be encrypted.
>
> This path is relative to private dir if the path does not start with a
> /.
>
> Default: tls keyfile = tls/key.pem

You have this set to `tls/mycert.crt`.  While a file named *mycert* which ends in `.crt` may be a private key, I suspect that its actually your certificate.

You should replace this with the private key file.

You should have previously created (or potentially received from the CA) the private key file.  You can verify that this file is in PEM format using `cat my.key` (insert correct name) where, if its in PEM format, it will begin with `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` (or potentially `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`).  If it shows up as a mix of text and non-printable characters when you view the file, then the file is in DER format, and you will need the help of a tool such as OpenSSL to convert this file to PEM.

---

> ##### tls certfile (G)
>
> This option can be set to a file (PEM format)
> containing the RSA certificate.
>
> This path is relative to private dir if the path does not start with a
> /.
>
> Default: tls certfile = tls/cert.pem

You have this set to `tls/thekey.p7b`.  Again, while a file named *thekey* with a `.p7b` extension may be a PEM encoded certificate, I suspect that it is a certificate or certificate bundle in PKCS#7 format.

You should replace this with the certificate file.

I'd suggest this should be `tls/mycert.crt`, but only if that file is in PEM format.  You can verify this with `cat mycert.crt` where, if its in PEM format, it will start `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`.  As for the private key, OpenSSL can help you convert between formats.

---

The `tls cafile = tls/myca.ca-bundle` could potentially be correct if the `myca.ca-bundle` file is a concatenation of PEM formatted CA certificates.  Again, use `cat` to view the file and it should contain one or more blocks beginning with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`.

---

If you fix the above, it should get you closer to a working Samba LDAPS.  However, note [this warning](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configuring_LDAP_over_SSL_(LDAPS)_on_a_Samba_AD_DC#SASL_over_TLS:_A_bad_idea) on the Samba wiki.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the question Gareth. The key and the cert are in the correct spots I just misnamed them when I renamed them for this question. I did have them all converted to a pem file in one instance, but next I will try just converting the key. Thank you so much for your detailed answer!